# When I try update something on a page in WP it redirects me to Posts list (/wp-admin/edit.php)

Tags: php, wordpress, updates

When I try to update or make changes to my pages in WP backend it redirects me to the posts lists (/wp-admin/edit.php) without saving. It also won't let me preview pages without redirecting.

Please help!

Many thanks

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a ticket system.  You have to explain what you have tried to do to fix it, as well as what you might think is wrong.  If you have code changes, share those too.

Comment: It's very helpful if you include code that shows the problem, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example as a place to start

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.